# Parsing XML on an open network Socket on android

Tags: java, android, xml, sockets, sax

Being new to android and java in general, I have been struggling with parsing xml from an open network socket.

The senario is as follows :-

I connect to a server that servers xml tags based on specific events. The client (android) needs to connect to the server and parse the tags as the server sends them. There is no EOL after any tags. The socket needs to remain open.

The problem is that SAX does not try to parse the xml until the socket has been closed.

I have searched from information to no avail.

Any pointers to example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you are getting a continuous XML stream? That may never end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a pull parser?

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html